# .htaccess rules working for some pages, but not for others

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cache-control, mod-deflate

I'm trying to use [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to speed up my website - www.edmhunters.com.

First off, here is what my `.htaccess` file looks like

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Caching for 1 Year
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|svg|woff|eot|ttf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Caching for 1 Week
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Defining MIME types to ensure the web server actually knows about them
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/javascript          js
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject   eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf          ttf ttc
    AddType font/opentype                   otf
    AddType application/x-font-woff         woff
    AddType image/svg+xml                   svg svgz 
    AddEncoding gzip                        svgz
</Ifmodule>

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compressing output
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
</Ifmodule>
```

The `Cache-Control` header strangely is working only for media files and not static files.

Eg. The output of http://www.edmhunters.com/media/dj/images/deadmau5_2.jpg on redbot.org looks like this

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Sun, 14 Sep 2014 06:01:54 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
    Last-Modified: Thu, 11 Sep 2014 13:52:29 GMT
    ETag: "7391-502ca7aba5a6e"
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Content-Length: 29585
    Cache-Control: max-age=604800, public
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

While the output of http://www.edmhunters.com/static/img/bp-logo.9bf55788f1b6.jpg looks like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Sun, 14 Sep 2014 05:43:28 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
    Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Aug 2014 05:43:32 GMT
    ETag: 1409031812.62
    Content-Length: 2592
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Also according to [Google PageSpeed Insights for my homepage](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=www.edmhunters.com%2F&tab=desktop) the HTML is minified, while [Google PageSpeed Insights for another page](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=www.edmhunters.com%2Favicii&tab=desktop) says my HTML is not minified.

Why this different behaviour?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is suitable for [webmaster.se]

Comment: @hjpotter92 Because it is on-topic for an other SE site doesn't mean it is off-topic for this site. SO in particular has quite some overlap with other SE sites. It might be a reason for OP to ask the question again on webmasters if it doesn't receive an answer here, but it is not really a reason to close it here.

Comment: @Sumurai8 By VTC as off-topic here, I'm helping the question to get migrated to the other site where the users have interest in the specific fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was serving my static files using Django while my media files using Apache. Serving my static files through Apache solved this issue.